# Как добавить маску ввода в поле календаря bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, bootstrap4, calendar

Есть календарь с [библиотекой datapicker](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Usage/) под `bootstrap 4`.

Интересует: как сделать так, чтобы `placeholder` был **dd/mm/yyyy**, а не **01/01/1970** как сейчас и можно было не только выбирать дату с помощью
всплывающего календаря,

но и заполнялись данные по маске при вводе данных, т.е. если ввожу в поле 10, то автоматически подставлялся `/` а не мне приходилось его дополнительно вводить ?

**P.S.** defaultDate: new Date(0) мне нужно, чтобы по умолчанию выводился диапазон века 1900-1990, а не 2000-2090

**Код:**

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  useCurrent: true,
  format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
  viewMode: 'decades',
  autoclose: true,
  defaultDate: new Date(0)
});
$('#datetimepicker1 input').mask("99/99/9999",{placeholder:"dd/mm/yyyy"});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.1.2/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.1.2/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>

<p><label for="date">DATE OF BIRTH</label><br /></p>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
    <input type="text" tabindex="4" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1" />
    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
      <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPD:** Добавил библиотеку [jquery.maskedinput](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js), но осталось 2 момента, которые хочется поправить:
 1. `placeholder` все равно какой-то непонятный, то такой **01/01/1970**, то **dd/mm/yyyy** - не знаю от чего это зависит.
 2. маска не ограничивает вводимые числа - как запретить пользователю вводить дату больше максимальной для дня (31), месяца (12), года (2099)

Comment: 01/01/1970 - это не плейсхолдер, а значение по умолчанию, уберите из инициализации строку `defaultDate: new Date(0)`

Comment: @Вадим Лешкевич я знаю, плейсхолдер у меня `placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"`, но мне нужно, чтобы по умолчанию выводился диапазон века 1900-1990, а не 2000-2090, поэтому и использую `defaultDate: new Date(0)`